# getting error "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController'"

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am creating spring mvc project in spring tool suite along with using hibernate having following details:

```
HomeController.java
package com.FruitStore.fruit;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.Fruit.Service.ServiceUser;
import com.FruitStore.Vo.VoUser;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    @Autowired
    ServiceUser serviceUser;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
        return "body";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Model model) {

        VoUser voUser=new VoUser();
        model.addAttribute("user", voUser);
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("user")VoUser voUser) {
        System.out.println(serviceUser);
        serviceUser.save(voUser);
        return "new";
    }
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.FruitStore" />
    <context:annotation-config />


</beans:beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource" /></property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
        <value>user.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="d" class="com.FruitStore.hibernate.DaoUserImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    </bean> 


    </beans>
```

ServiceUser.java

```
package com.Fruit.Service;
import com.FruitStore.Vo.VoUser;
import com.FruitStore.hibernate.User;
/**
 * 
 * @author kaif
 *
 */
public interface ServiceUser {

    void save(User user);
    void update(User user);
    void delete(User user);
    void save(VoUser user);


}
```

ServiceUserImpl.java

```
package com.Fruit.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.FruitStore.Vo.VoUser;
import com.FruitStore.hibernate.DaoUser;
import com.FruitStore.hibernate.User;


@Service
public class ServiceUserImpl implements ServiceUser{

    @Autowired
    private DaoUser daoUser;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        daoUser.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        daoUser.update(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {
        daoUser.delete(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(VoUser user) {
        daoUser.save(user);

    }

}
```

DaoUser.java

```
package com.FruitStore.hibernate;
import com.FruitStore.Vo.VoUser;

public interface DaoUser {
    void save(User user);
    void update(User user);
    void delete(User user);
    void save(VoUser user);

}
```

DaoUserImpl.java

```
package com.FruitStore.hibernate;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.FruitStore.Vo.VoUser;

@Repository("DaoUser")
public class DaoUserImpl implements DaoUser {

    HibernateTemplate template;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory session)
    {
        template=new HibernateTemplate(session);
    }
    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
            template.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        template.update(user);      
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {
        template.delete(user);      
    }

    @Override
    public void save(VoUser vouser)
    {
       User user=new User();
       user.setUsername(vouser.getUsername());
       user.setEmail(vouser.getAddress());
       user.setPassword(vouser.getPassword());
       user.setAddress(vouser.getAddress()+vouser.getCountry());
       this.save(user);

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.FruitStore</groupId>
    <artifactId>fruit</artifactId>
    <name>FruitStore</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>            
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

But when i try to run the project i am getting the error "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController'" however if i don't use the @Autowired annotation in HomeController.java then i get the daoUser value as Null. can you help me to figure this out.

Comment: A more consistent stack trace would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the entire .m2(maven directory) and reinstall all dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In your `root-context.xml`/`applicationContext.xml` you need a `<context:component-scan />` which scans for everything but controllers. You have one but that one doesn't include the packages in which you have defined your services.

Add the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.FruitStore,com.fruit">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
<context:component-scan>
```

This also allows you to remove the definition for your `DaoUserImpl` bean as this will now be picked up by component-scanning. You will need to add an `@Autowired` to the `setSessionFactory` method to make that work.

Change the one in your `servlet-context.xml` to the follwoing

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.FruitStore,com.fruit" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
<context:component-scan>
```

Also remove `<context:annotation-config />` that is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`.

A final note on your `DaoUserImpl` please don't use `HibernateTemplate` that should be considered deprecated as of the release of hibernate 3.0.1 (around in 2006). Use the `SessionFactory` directly and use the `getCurrentSession()` method. See also http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight for more information.

Comment: i change my code as you suggested but i am getting following error

Comment: Dec 06, 2013 3:13:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/fruit/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: Update your question with the configuration you use now.

Comment: You read my answer wrong... You added the wrong configuration element to the servet-context.xml. Read my anwser.

Comment: sorry i read it wrong now i make the correction. can you please look at it

Comment: Have you added the other `component-scan` to your `root-context.xml` (as explained in my answer?). I guess not (or your packages don't match).

Comment: is it mandatory to add the component-scan in root-context.xml as i have added it in applicationcontext.xml

Comment: As long as that gets loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` it should be fine (your code/post is a bit messy so I lost track of a lot of stuff). Judging from the stacktrace (and your copy/pasting) the packages are wrong (an dyou aren't following Java naming guidelines). Your package is `com.Fruit` and not `com.fruit`.

Comment: so can you please tell me what to do now?

Comment: You should be able to figure that one out yourself. The package names do not match. You have `com.Fruit` and you copy pasted `com.fruit`, so what do you think you need to do!

Comment: ok i got that my package names are wrong. let me try once more after mofifying package names

Comment: either that or simply change the `base-packages` to `com.Fruit`. However your package naming/structure seems to be some kind of mess. I strongly suggest you do some reading on java standard conventions.

Comment: I modify the package names and also make changes in servlet-context.xml and applicationContext.xml but still i am getting same error!!!

Comment: If you modified both, they still don't match. Please modify your question (and not post another answer). I totally lost overview what you have, and your naming conventions. Can you post the code somewhere?

Comment: should i send you my project to you on your email or something like that

Comment: i Have upload the project at bitbucket.org here is the link to pull the project  https://keshav91@bitbucket.org/keshav91/fruitstore.git

Comment: The problem is in your configuration, fix it. YOur code is inaccesible so we cannot have a look. What you posted here is getting incomprehensible. As mentioned fix your packages, read up on spring as you seem to be lacking the basics.

Comment: here is the link from where you can download the project              https://github.com/kaif91/FruitStore and  as i am in learning stage please help me to sort out where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Your root-context.xml is completely empty, basically your applicationContext.xml is pretty much useless as that isn't being loaded. Either let the `ContextLoaderListener` also load the applicationContext.xml or import it in your root-context.xml.

Comment: i tried to make contextLoaderListener to load the applicationContext.xml but i am still getting error. can you have any other way out